# Show/Hide Column in Views Table

Tags: 7, views, javascript

Is there any way I can show/hide entire column in Views Table?

**Exclude from Display** completely excludes the column which is not possible to show again, so, I am using [Views Dynamic Fields Module](https://drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields) to exclude the column initially and showing it when the filter is checked. Like in the picture, the initial view when Column is hidden using ***Views Dynamic Fields*** module.

[image]

When the ***Nick Name*** checkbox is checked the column is shown like:

[image]

However, I want to hide the ***Name*** Column entirely when ***Nick Name*** is shown.

I initially tried it with **jQuery** like:

```
// Hide the Name Column when Nick Name is shown
$('#edit-dyfield-field-girls-nickname').change(function() { // id of checkbox
                if ($('#edit-dyfield-field-girls-nickname').is(':checked')) {
                    $('.views-field-title').hide(); // Title points to Name field so all the th td have this class in Name
                }
            });
```

But it hides both *Name* and *Nick Name* for a while, and shows both fields again.

Any solution Drupal based or some tricks with jQuery/JavaScript would be fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is **The Drupal Way** to fix this, but I fixed it with jQuery `hide()` and `show()`.

```
// Hide the Name Column when Nick Name is shown
$('#edit-dyfield-field-girls-nickname').change(function() {
                if ($('#edit-dyfield-field-girls-nickname').is(':checked')) {
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function() { // Forcefully stopping Ajax function in the page as other ajax load was main culprit in my case
                        $('.views-field-title').hide();
                    });
                }

                if ($('#edit-dyfield-field-girls-nickname').is(':not(:checked)')) {
                    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                        $('.views-field-title').show();
                    });
                }

            });
```

**Note**: In the above example jQuery `toggle()` doesn't work, so, I have to put 2 `if(){}` statements for ***Check*** and ***UnCheck***.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Views MediaTable](https://drupal.org/project/views_mediatable) module.

Not sure if this is the exact use case you are after. this will allow the user to select the columns they want to see.

> Views MediaTable integrate the functionality of
>   MediaTable(http://consulenza-web.com/jquery/MediaTable/) into the
>   Views module Table display, allowing the creation of dynamic &
>   responsive Views tables where end users can choose to show or hide
>   certain columns. This module also allows certain table column to
>   behave responsively, hiding the less relevant data in smaller screen
>   sizes.

The js code you used should also do the trick. But the issue you are facing is due to ajax loading. so you will have to put in drupal behavior so it gets called even after the ajax call.

You can check out the below link for more information regarding adding js

[Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722)

Comment: I have already used that module, its great for responsive table when the size of viewport shrinks, it hides the columns entirely, but it doesn't have option to use how I want with checkbox.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this line **you will have to put in drupal behavior so it gets called even after the ajax call** I guess I am stuck here, if you could help me do this then `jQuery` trick is fine. BTW I have that **jQuery** code inside 
`(function($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
        attach: function(context, settings) { 
// Mycode 
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);`

Comment: Let me get your requirement correct. you want a check box and when it is clicked you want to hide name and display nickname. and when unchecked you want to display the name and hide the nickname. Is that right?

Comment: yes sir, that's what I have been trying to acheive